# unable to deinstall office 2010 professional

Tags: ms-office, uninstallation

Im unable to deinstall office 2010 on my windows 10 workstation. I have done an update from Windows 7 to Windows 10, but i dont know weather the uninstaller was missing before or not.

I tried every solution, which is described in https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Uninstall-or-remove-Office-2010-90635a1d-aec8-4653-b358-67e1b766fc4d. The uninstaller is missing in the control panel, the fix it program doesnt work and the .msi-files are missing too.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You can download some program to uninstall it. If it doesn't recognized it, search in the installation folder for uninstall icon. Last solution is to physically delete installation folder and to delete key from regedit.